# using the variable in LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE

Tags: php, windows, ldap

I am using authentication on a domain network with several domain controllers. I define the certificate and the path according to which domain the user is logged on to. I wanted to clean up the code by putting the path and names in the application parameters.

this works perfectly :

```
ldap_set_option(null, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE, 'C:\install\certif\HAVEX-DC1-CA.pem');
```

But this:

```
$certpath=$this->globalparameter->parameters["constants"]["CertifPath"]; 
$certname=$this->globalparameter->parameters["constants"]["CertifHXA"];
$x=$certpath.'\\'.$certname; 
$ldap_set_option(null, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE, $x);
```

Unfortunately, it ends up with an Undefined variable error.

[list of variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pJV1.png)

Can it be used like this?

Comment: You should be able to use a variable like that but can you confirm that it has been populated with meaningful data prior to using it (ie: does it print the path you expect if you test it )

Comment: The correct path was in the variable. I verified this with dump($x).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with `$x` – it's `$ldap_set_option` is the "undefined variable" here. You somehow turned a standard function call into a variable-name call.